# Dynamically add sortOrder into existing column of extendedDataTable

Tags: session, jsf, sorting, datatable

In my project, I have many views using extendedDataTable. Now, I want to make sorting on these table preserved in session. So I add sortOrder="#sessionData.columnSortOrders[columnUniqueName]}" to the columns.
How I can do this in a more generic way that effect all existing table?

Thanks!